# SQL Server 2005 can't increase log file size

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a small SQL Server 2005 DB (one data partition 21MB, one log file 10MB initial size).

Users are getting an error that the log file is full.  Upon checking, it is full and currently 10MB even though it's set to auto-grow in 10% increments with no max size limit.

When I try to manually increase the size of the log file in MSMS Express, I get the error:

MODIFY FILE encountered operating system error 112(There is not enough space on the disk while attempting to expand the physical file. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5149).

However, there are currently 117GB of free disk space on the C: drive (where the log file is written), waaay larger than the DB and the log file combined.  There are no disk space user quotas.

Is something restricting the max amount of disk space available to SQL Server?  Other thoughts?

UPDATE:

I deleted an old database that resided on the same drive (freeing up around 20MB) and this did not change the situation.

SOLUTION:

Found a [solution](http://blog.crankybit.com/shrink-the-unshrinkable-sql-transaction-log/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

[Found a solution](http://blog.crankybit.com/shrink-the-unshrinkable-sql-transaction-log/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd double check that it's actually manipulating the file you think it's manipulating. Sometimes using sysinternals (free utility suit) and running filemon, regmon, or procmon can yield some information that is helpful on what access attempts are failing.

I'd also try a chkdsk on the volume to make sure nothing is corrupted in the filesystem.